# File is not writable problem in xcode?

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, macbook, xcode

I created one user and gaveallow user to administrate this computer.But when I logged through that user ,I could not edit  and save my xcode project files File is not writable error comes..it did not allow to edit the files.I checked  in xcode preferences for saving.even I am facing same problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X is a multi-user operating system with the concept of file owners and file permissions. If another user created a file, it's possible that the new account does not have permissions. Check the "Get Info" dialog of your files at the bottom. If it doesn't say "You can read and write" you need to change the permissions (enable that part of the dialog via the lock icon).